Mirror traffic to two different loadbalancers
We have infrastructure that receives traffic from devices through a route53 subdomain pointed to a load balancer. The domain is configured on the devices and its not feasible to update/add another domain on each device.
I want the same traffic load to be mirrored to our stage environment that has a separate load balancer.
so if a request reaches production, it should reach stage env at the same time.
Can this be achieved at the DNS level without adding another layer that will effect performance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

where would the responses go? if its load balance-able traffic then it is almost certainly a request-response stream, and a client isn't going to expect multiple responses to a request. this seems really odd. its a webserver right? I don't know of any webservers where you can't have multiple name bindings for a site, as long as your have a certificate that lists all the domains in the subject or SAN fields.

@FrankThomas
Edited my question.
The loadbalancer is an entrypoint to a service which in turn is a source of data for other services hosted on kubernetes.
No client will not get multiple responses
